# Flickr: Python - find panoramic pictures

Tags: python, flickr

Am trying to use he Flickr Python API to do something I thought should be quite simple but am pulling my hair out.

I would like to find all pictures by my username and password, that are panoramic. I am guessing that the proxy for panoramic would be such that the aspect ratio is greater than 5:7 or 4:6 unless there's specific metadata on Flickr I can filter by.

I would like to then download all of them onto my desktop.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

The [flickr.photos.getSizes](https://www.flickr.com/services/api/explore/flickr.photos.getSizes) endpoint gives you the pixel dimensions of all available versions of an image.  Look for the Original-sized image; use the pixel dimensions (width= and height=) to compute the aspect ratio; and filter accordingly.